# Javascript lookup in a table that has minimum and maximum values of latitude and longitude and return the grid value

Tags: javascript, minmax

I have a latitude /longitude pair that i gets from a json . Requirement is that I need to return the grid value corresponding to that latitude/longitude pair.
I have this table that has the min and max values for the latitude and longitude for a corresponding value. it looks like this :

[image: min_max_grid_table]

I am new to javascript. How can i code a function / a code to get the value after checking if the incoming latitude and longitude falls within the range for each grid value? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like you need to find min/max for each grid?

Comment: What is the grid name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I interpret your question properly, but try this.

```js
const [latitude, longitude] = [117.5783, -33.6768];

function getData() {
    const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
    const rows = [...tbody.rows];
    const data = rows.map(row => {
        const [minLng, minLat, maxLng, maxLat, gridName] = [...row.cells].map(
            cell => cell.textContent
        );

        return {
            minLng: +minLng,
            minLat: +minLat,
            maxLng: +maxLng,
            maxLat: +maxLng,
            gridName
        };
    });

    return data;
}

function getGridValue({ latitude, longitude }) {
    const data = getData();

    const item = data.find(
        item =>
            (item.minLat >= latitude || item.maxLat <= latitude) ||
            (item.minLng >= longitude || item.maxLng <= longitude)
    );

    if (item) {
        return item.gridName;
    }

    return null;
}
const value = getGridValue({ latitude, longitude });

console.log(value);
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>MIN_LNG</th>
            <th>MIN_LAT</th>
            <th>MAX_LNG</th>
            <th>MAX_LAT</th>
            <th>GRIDname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>117.5783</td>
            <td>-33.6764</td>
            <td>117.5787</td>
            <td>-33.6766</td>
            <td>5c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>117.5783</td>
            <td>-33.6766</td>
            <td>117.5785</td>
            <td>-33.6768</td>
            <td>4c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>117.5783</td>
            <td>-33.6768</td>
            <td>117.5785</td>
            <td>-33.6770</td>
            <td>3c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

First I simulate the pair of data you get from json `const [latitude, longitude] = [117.5783, -33.6768];`

The `getData` function obtains the data from an html table, so I am unaware of the origin of the data. I do this because it is easier to work with arrays and objects than with DOM nodes

The function `getGridValue` searches the data and if the condition is fulfilled it will return the value of the `gridName` property otherwise it will return `null`

Again, I hope I have interpreted your question properly, I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much user615274 for giving me the insight. I tweaked the code little bit and here is the final code that I generated with the help of your code.

```
grid_table = [
{"minLng":"117.5783","minLat":"-33.6764","maxLng": "117.5787","maxLat":"-33.6766","gridName" :"5c"},
{"minLng":"117.5783","minLat":"-33.6766","maxLng":"117.5785","maxLat":"-33.6768","gridName":"4c"},
{"minLng":"117.5783","minLat":"-33.6768","maxLng":"117.5785","maxLat":"-33.6770","gridName":"3c"}
]

function getGridValue({ latitude, longitude }) {
    const data = [...grid_table];

    const item = data.find(
        item =>
            (latitude >= item.minLat  && longitude >= item.minLng) &&
            (latitude <= item.maxLat && longitude <= item.maxLng)
    );

    if (item) {
        return item.gridName;
    }

    return null;
}
const [latitude, longitude] = ["-33.6769","117.5784"];
const value = getGridValue({ latitude, longitude});

document.write(value);
```

Thank you so much. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or furthur thoughts.